# Sign in with Google - What should I do with `nonce`?

Tags: google-signin

What I'm doing now:

1. Using the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=en) to render the button on my web page.
2. When the Sign in with Google flow is complete, my client-side JavaScript callback is called.
3. That callback sends the given `.credentials` string to my server.
4. The backend server (Node.js) calls the [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#readme) library's `OAuth2Client.verifyIdtoken` method on the `.credentials` string, which returns the user's email address (among other things), which my server uses to verify the user and create a session.

Everything works, but I'm wondering if there are any security concerns I'm missing.  In particular there's a `nonce` field.  The docs ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=en#nonce)) don't explain how to use it.

Note: I'm using ["Sign in with Google"](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview?hl=en) and not the deprecated ["Google Sign-In"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

**Edit**: I'm familiar with the concept of nonces and have used them when doing the OAuth 2 server-side flow myself.  What I can't figure out is how the Sign in with Google SDK expects me to use its `nonce` parameter with the flow above, where I'm using both their client-side and server-side SDKs.

Answer (score 3):

Nonces are used as a CSRF-prevention method. When you make a request to Google, you include a nonce, and when authentication is complete, Google will send the same nonce back. The magic in this method is that if the nonce does not match what you sent then you can ignore the response, because it was probably spoofed.

Read more about CSRF here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf

Nonces are usually crytographically secure random strings/bytes.

I use `crypto-random-string` as a base to generate nonces, but any package with this functionality should suffice.

Sometimes I store nonces with a TTL in Redis, but other times I store nonces with an ID attached to the request so I can later verify it.

I'm telling you this since it took a bit long for me to figure out this nonce stuff :P

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept of nonces in general, and have used them when doing the OAuth 2 server-side flow myself.  What I can't figure out is how the Sign in with Google SDK expects me to use its `nonce` parameter in my particular setup, where I'm using both their client-side and server-side SDKs.

Comment: Add the nonce to each sign-in request made by the the client SDK, check for it in the response handled by the server-side SDK on your back end. Typically, you'll process the JWT on your back-end (via redirect) and nonce is included within the signed object so you can safely avoid replay attacks. Sign-in requests might originate from a browser based web app, a native Android, or iOS app. You'll want to match these requests 1:1 to the response and the secure place to do so is your back end server which receives the redirect and signed JWT and it's embedded nonce.

Answer (score 3):

Using the example from Google's website (https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/idtoken-auth), I added the code for the nonce:

```
const nonce = '...'; // Supplied by client in addition to token
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const serverNonce = payload['nonce'];
  if (nonce != serverNonce) {
    // Return an error
  }

  const userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  // const domain = payload['hd'];
}
verify().catch(console.error);
```